# Determine the values of c for which the equation Ax = b is consistent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Determine the values of c for which the equation Ax = b is consistent.

A= \begin{pmatrix}3&2&5&-1&-4\\2&1&4&2&-4\\1&-3&9&-2&15\\4&2&8&1&-5\end{pmatrix}

x:= \begin{pmatrix}x1\\x2\\x3\\x4\\x5\end{pmatrix}

b= \begin{pmatrix}1\\5\\-14\\c\end{pmatrix}

The way I was planning on going about this question was to put matricies A and B into an augmented matrix, and then use row operations to find the RREF, then you would get an equation for C. Can anyone either say that is the best way to find C or give me another way to work out the values of C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with your way of solving this problem! By rewriting the whole problem into an augmented matrix you'll get a better overview and by forming the augmented matrix into RREF you'll find via parametrization the value(s) of $c$.
$$\left(
 \begin{matrix}
  3 & 2 & 5 & -1 & -4\\
  2 & 1 & 4 & 2 & -4\\
  1 & -3 & 9 & -2 & 15\\
  4 & 2 & 8 & 1 & -5
 \end{matrix}
 \left|
  \begin{matrix}
   1\\
   5\\
   -14\\
   c
  \end{matrix}
 \right)
\right.$$

just as a help (if you solve it by hand) the RREF of A is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 & -4\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If you want to solve it by hand it is up to you but it is way easier and faster to solve it in matlab if you have access to it. Use the commands rref, solve and combine to get to your solution in matlab. I hope you get along with this piece of advice.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is definitely the best way to do this problem by hand.